# How to Structure Lists

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting, dictionary, collections

I am working on a vb.net auto-focus routine and have the image processing part worked out, basically I do some edge detection, convert to gray-scale and then measure the standard deviation to work out the most 'in focus' point of the image.

I have done this with a number of images, and it almost comes out as a normal distribution, now I want to start to integrate this with my microscope and a stepper motor.

The concept is that I would move through a lower and upper limit on the stepper motor, and measure the above through live-view, recording the values in a list. In my case the two things I want to record are the position, and the double standard deviation value.

> I am wondering what the best way to record these are, should it be
>   recorded as a typed list, or a dictionary or another method?

Once I record all of these values, I would want to go through the values to conduct some simple analysis of them, so if that was the case

> how would I then be able to determine the average, min, max etc?

My first attempt of storing the information was in a typed list, where I had essentially done the below;

```
Public ZPositions As New List(Of Zfocus)    

Public Class Zfocus
Public Position As Integer
Public GreyStDev As Double
End Class
```

The second way was to use a dictionary;

```
 Public ZPosition As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Double)
```

However in both cases, I am not sure how I can either pull out a single maximum position value (e.g. Position integer,) or from the dictionary the position value (integer) which (sort of) corrosponds to the best auto-focus position.

> The Third added bonus, is to be able to pull out any postions above a
>   specific value, which may corrospond to having some focus information
>   within them for focus stacking?

Many thanks

Comment: The first thing to do is to decide whether a `Dictionary` actually makes sense.  Once the data is stored, would it make sense to specify a Position to get the corresponding GreyStDev?  Are the Position values true keys or are they just part of the data?  I'm guessing the latter.

Comment: Getting average, minimum and maximum values is dead easy because there are LINQ methods that correspond to all three.  You can also use the LINQ `Where` method for you third issue.

Comment: So the keys are not true keys, just part of the data. They will not always be starting low as well. It may be the case that in the Stepper code I start from Step 10021 and move to step 19999 (as an example) so I am not tied to dictionary.

Comment: In that case, I'd go with the `List`.  You can then do things like `avgGreyStDev = ZPositions.Avg(Function(zp) zp.GreyStDev)` and `minPosition = ZPositions.First(Function(zp1) zp1.Position = ZPositions.Min(Function(zp2) zp2.Position))`.

Comment: So the keys are not true keys, just part of the data. They will not always be starting low as well. It may be the case that in the Stepper code I start from Step 10021 and move to step 19999 (as an example) so I am not tied to dictionary. Also as an aside, this is not needed for long terms storage rather just to determine at that point the best focus points. At the start of the project I would move to a test point to determine the 'acceptable threshold' but after that it would just clear the list after each 'test'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to jmcilhinney, this solved my issue and works a treat!
Went with a strongly typed list (the ZFocus list) and then I could do the below;

```
MaxPosition = ZPositions.First(Function(zp1) zp1.GreyStDev = ZPositions.Max(Function(zp2) zp2.GreyStDev))
```

This allowed be to set up an auto-focus routine which loops through a number of images (as a test), stores the position (e.g. image number in this case) and the intensity edge information, and at the end then pull out the strongest intensity information which forms the best auto-focus point in my case